# HTML canvas: unsatisfying results when drawing a border around a filled shape

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fill, stroke

Here are 4 examples on how to draw (in an HTML canvas) a filled shape with a border. Only one of them gives a clean result and I wish to understand why:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
let border = 2;

// integer coordinates
usingStroke(ctx, 50, 50, border, 1);
usingFill(ctx, 150, 50, border, 2);

// half-pixel shift
usingStroke(ctx, 50.5, 150.5, border, 3);
usingFill(ctx, 150.5, 150.5, border, 4);
ctx.restore();

function usingStroke(ctx, x, y, border, text) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.rect(x+10, y, 50, 30);
    ctx.lineWidth = border * 2; //half of it will be behind the fill

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'darkred';
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.fillStyle = 'salmon';
    ctx.fill();

    addText(ctx, text, x, y);
}

function usingFill(ctx, x, y, border, text) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 25 + border, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.rect(x+10-border, y-border, 50+border*2, 30+border*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'darkred';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.rect(x+10, y, 50, 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'salmon';
    ctx.fill();

    addText(ctx, text, x, y);
}

function addText(ctx, text, x, y) {
    ctx.font = "bold 20px sans";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

It uses two different methods:

- examples 1 and 3 use `stroke` first for the border, then `fill` for the background.
- examples 2 and 4 draw the shape twice using `fill` both times: a bit larger the first time, with the border color, and at the right size the second time.

I also know that lines (and borders) of odd width tend to be blurry, and need to be drawn a half-pixel further to get a crisp result (hence the exemples 3 and 4). [More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#a_linewidth_example).

What I don't understand is:

1. why is example 2 the only one giving a crisp result?
2. why do example 1 and 3 (using `stroke`) give a non-homogenous border? The border appears thicker at the top left thant at the bottom right of the shape(s). At first I thought that it was just an artefact of the low resolution and that adding a half-pixel would solve it, but no...

In conclusion, I feel frustrated with the `stroke` approach and wonder if there is a better way to use it. I know it works well with thicker borders, but I only work with borders of 1 to 3 pixels.

Comment: Your questions do not match the rendered content. Q1... shape 1 is identical to 2 and Q2... shapes 1 and 3 have no *"non-homogenous"* border (top and bottom lines are identical (when flipped)) Using uptodate Chrome Win11 and ignoring the circle, shape 1 matches 2 and shape 3 matches 4 (pixel and color perfect, from a screenshot and aligned using bottom right most pixel of each shape). Please specify the browser and OS you are seeing the inconsistencies on.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I use Firefox 118 on Ubuntu 22.04, which gives these non-homogenous widths. When trying on Chromium 118 still on Ubuntu 22.04, the border appear homogenous (results 1 & 2 are almost identical).
As for the non-crip results: even in Chromium, 1 & 3 still feel a bit more blurry on the circle than 2 and 4, but I can work with that. I'll continue to investigage it, but we can leave the current question at that.

Comment: Probably caused by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1860502 As for Chrome's blurriness of 1 & 2, you're probably on a high-res monitor, you'd need to compensate for that by scaling your canvas down with CSS. For 3 & 4 it's expected to be blurry, as you said yourself the 0.5 offset works for when stroking with an odd lineWidth, here the lineWidth is `4` there is no reason for such an offset, and there is never a reason for it when filling.

Comment: Yes, the bug you point seems to fit with the odd shift I see. Thank you. As for the blurriness I did try with different pixel ratios, but still feel unsatisfied. I already scale up my canvas when drawing then scale it down through CSS to diminish that effect on example 2 (which is the solution I am currently using). Bah, it doesn't matter, I will continue with this approach.